# Is this query slow

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Is this a slow query based on the value of that Explain? I'm on MySQL.

[image]

Comment: Slow is relative. Can your query be made faster? Absolutely: your indexes are not covering, and you may be able to get rid of temporary/filesort, depending on your query. But that doesn't mean it's slow. It might currently need 0.05s, when it could be optimized to 0.049s. If you need help optimizing the query, you would need to provide the query, table structure/indexes, general information about table size and how many rows are part of your resultset. Also, if applicable, anomalies about your data distribution, e.g. a value that you filter for that only appears in 1 row out of 10 million.

Answer (score 1):

"Index merge intersect" can almost always be sped up by providing a composite index.

```
INDEX(dealerID, orgID)  -- (I can't tell if the order matters.)
```

But that is all I can deduce from the `EXPLAIN` without also seeing `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT`.